# How to change the color of Placeholder in Div?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am a bit stuck to change the color of the Placeholder in div. I am using VueJs to bind placeholder with my div element.
Here is the front-end :

[image]

> VueJs Code :

```
<div class="new-message-input form-control" id="plc" contenteditable :data-placeholder="$t('chat.type_a_message')" :placeholder="$t('chat.type_a_message')" ref="newMessageInput" @keydown="isTyping" @keydown.enter="enterPressedEvt(postMessage, $event)">
```

> Css Code :

```
#plc::placeholder { 
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) applies only to `<input>` or `<textarea>` (not `<div>`). Why not use an `<input>` here?

Comment: @tony19 It is the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#plc{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="plc" contentEditable=true data-text="Type a message..."></div>
```